# Writing data to screen twice instead of once

Tags: java, android, terminal

I am connecting to a terminal emulator using a library in android, this connects to a serial device (a switch) and shows me sent/received data. I send data over serial using another library. I send data over the connection via a text box below the terminal or by typing in the terminal itself and hitting enter on the keyboard in both cases. When I send via `editText` everything works fine. Data is sent and received and displayed on the terminal.

However when I select the terminal and type characters, these are displayed on screen and sent directly to the write method, without being sent over serial. If I send them over serial from the write method they get displayed twice on the terminal.

In my activity I have a method called `sendOverSerial` which just calls a library method to send data over serial. It sends the data, then data is received from the serial device and `onDataReceieved` is automatically called.

```
public static void sendOverSerial(byte[] data) {

    if(mSelectedAdapter !=null && data !=null){
    mSelectedAdapter.sendData(data);

  }}
```

Method that is called when data is received:

```
 public void onDataReceived(int id, byte[] data) {

            dataReceived = new String(data);
            dataReceivedByte = data;
            statusBool = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "in data received " + dataReceived);
            ((MyBAIsWrapper) bis).renew(data);


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //this line writes to the terminal
                    mSession.appendToEmulator(dataReceivedByte, 0, dataReceivedByte.length);
                }});

            viewHandler.post(updateView);
        }
```

Generally when I want to send data over serial, via the editText and buttons I call the sendOverSerial method in the activity. But when I am writing characters into the terminal itself they are picked up in a different classes write method. My problem is if I call the sendOverSerial method from that instance where the data is recieved it is written twice to the screen, once when I press the key, and then again when the data is sent over serial and onDataReceived is called.

Here is the write method in the second class:

```
 public void write(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count) {


//this line ends up calling onDataReceived which writes to the terminal again
//I need it to send the data over serial
             GraphicsTerminalActivity.sendOverSerial(data);
     if (isRunning()) {
                 //this line writes to the terminal
                 //I need this line for my editText data to be written to the screen
         doLocalEcho(bytes);
     }
     return;
 }
```

doLocalEcho:

```
private void doLocalEcho(byte[] data) {
        String str = new String(data);
        appendToEmulator(data, 0, data.length);
        notifyUpdate();
    }
```

I enter a character on the terminal, this character is sent to `write` automatically. Here it is written to the screen with `super.write(bytes, offset, count);` but next `GraphicsTerminalActivity.sendOverSerial(data);` is called which sends the data over serial and induces an echo from the serial device, meaning `onDataReceived` will write the character to the screen again.

How could I change the code so that only one character is displayed to the screen?
If I move  `GraphicsTerminalActivity.sendOverSerial(bytes);` to `onDataRecieved` an infinite loop happens, so I can't put it in there instead.